# How to know Metro Viewstete is not in fullscreen

Tags: css, microsoft-metro, viewstate

I am implementing Metro app, and stuck on the viewstate.

I have two viewstate, for fullscreen and non-full screen

The following is my code which trys to apply non-fullscreen style by determining 
max-width's percentage but not work

```
/*default css style for fullscreen   */
.class1 {}
.class2 {}

/* non-fullscreen style */
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 99%) {
.class1 {}
.class2 {}
}
```

Are there any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link [max width for winjs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh996909.aspx)

And also a point mentioned in this link

** If the width of the containing block is not explicitly set, then the element has no maximum width and the max-width property is interpreted as 0%**

if this does not seem to help then share your html please. ill proceed configuring that and even would be helpful to get the exact problem.